# DB2 - select last inserted 5 rows from a table

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table that has no indexed rows, nor a specific column...

Let's say "City, PersonName, PersonAge". I need to obtain the ***last*** 5 people inserted in that table...

How can I do it in in DB2?

I tried

```
select * from PEOPLE fetch first 5 rows only
```

this work perfectly... but no idea how to do it with the LAST rows....

Comment: just curious, why would you store the age of a person in a database ? Wouldn't it be more productive to store the birthday ?

Comment: @ t-clausen.dk I don't store the age, the example was just theoretical...

Comment: If it's theoretical, then why not add a unique identifier that will meet your needs?

Comment: I am confused about the possibility to select **first** 5 rows (without any additional hack), but the impossibility to select the 5 last rows in the same way...

Answer (score 4):

You can't select the last 5 rows inserted, the database doesn't keep track of this. You need some sort of autoincremented ID or timestamp and order by that column descending.

Comment: so, how is it possible that the database keep the track of the FIRST inserted rows, but does not keep the track about the LAST inserted rows?

Comment: @Serge the database is not keeping track of the first inserted rows eather. When you write fetch first 5 rows, the database is returning the first 5 rows it encounter. No guarantee it is the first 5 inserted

Comment: @Serge Since you're using DB2, it probably looks like it's in "order" for the first few rows because the field you're looking at is probably part of (or *the*) ["clustering index"](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0061098.html), which defines how the rows are physically ordered. If a DBA ran a [`REORG`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001966.html), then it would probably be "in order", but that's not **guaranteed** unless you include an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @bhamby You are correct, in that DB2 does not guarantee what order rows are returned, except as far as an ORDER BY clause specified. As a DB2 for i DBA, I would point out that the reasons you gave are platform specific to DB2 LUW. On IBM i if a table does not have a primary index, then the records would most likely be delivered in physical sequence, but that is not guaranteed to be the arrival sequence, before any reorg.

Comment: @bhamby many of us here tend to assume someone mentioning DB2 means LUW. And there are easily more people on this site who use DB2 LUW than z/OS or IBM i. But I hear from a knowledgeable source that more businesses use DB2 for i than any other.

Comment: @WarrenT, it's always a fun exercise to remember the differences between i, LUW, and z/OS. Having mostly worked with the latter two, I don't know a whole lot about the i Series product.

Comment: @bhamby by default our indexes are binary radix (without mention of clustering). Our other type is an encoded vector index, which is (so far) unique to IBM i, far superior to bitmap indexes.

Comment: I am not a database pro, so maybe I miss something... But as for me, if is legal to see "first 5", so we can talk about a ordered list... If this order is not guaranteed that means that there is no order - we can't guarantee nor 5 first, nor 5 last. If we can guarantee 5 first, we should be able to guarantee 5 last... I can't add a order by, because I want to see just the last added items, nor I can't add a custom column, because in my case the table is readonly for me. I am supposed to read or write the data in the table, not to modify it... so, finally, the answer is "not possible"...